# Can I get Akka HTTP to backpressure when it encounters an error?

Tags: scala, akka-stream, akka-http

I'm using Akka HTTP in a project and for certain flows, we have external infrastructure that can easily become overloaded, throwing back HTTP 500-level errors when we do POST requests (which in our case are idempotent).  In these instances, we retry the request like so:

```scala
    RetryFlow.withBackoff(minBackoff = retryMin.seconds, maxBackoff = retryMax.seconds, randomFactor = 0d, maxRetries = numRetries, httpReqRespFlow)(
      decideRetry = { (request, response) =>
        response.httpResponse match {
          case Success(httpResponse: HttpResponse) =>
            if(httpResponse.status.isSuccess()) {
              None
            } else {
              processHttpResponseFailure(request, httpResponse)
            }
          case Failure(exception: Exception) =>
            logger.error(s"Retrying HTTP request from ${response.httpResponse} future failure", exception)
            response.httpResponse.map(_.discardEntityBytes())
            Some(request)
        }
      }
    )

   }.log("Backoff HTTP request")
```

I understand that Akka HTTP will [backpressure if the `entityBytes` are not consumed or discarded](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/implications-of-streaming-http-entity.html) but is there any way for me to force the flow to backpressure when we get these load-related errors?  There will be several streams of execution, and ideally, I'd like the whole system to "throttle back" if it starts to overload the downstream system.

Comment: Looks like RetryFlow.withBackoff already does the job, doesn't it?

Comment: It might, but I'm not sure.  It'll slow down a single flow or thread if it runs into errors, but what if I have multiple flows and multiple threads?  I'd like to be able to guarantee that everything slows down when we start running into errors, not just a single thread.

Comment: Then you need to throttle some stream from other stream. This sounds like hacking, but if you are into it, I think you need something like Valve (https://github.com/akka/akka-stream-contrib/blob/master/src/main/scala/akka/stream/contrib/Valve.scala)... but better. Valve can be only open or closed, but you need to throttle elements in a stream.